# Rspec testing Sentry's Raven capture_exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sentry

Let's say I have this snippet of code...

```
  Raven.capture_exception(error, {
    extra: {
      error_message: message
    }
  })
end
```

I have tried to use `expect(Raven).to receive(:capture_exception).with(...)` and no matter how I slice this, I can not seem to bind an expect to Raven so I can verify it was sent the logging communications.  It keeps telling me `capture_exception` is not defined.  I have tried both `expect` and `expect_any_instance_of` with no luck.  For now, I have skipped this, but I know there is a way. Thoughts?

Comment: You want to stub `Raven.capture_exception`, right?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to test the basic functionality of the gem, but why?  It seems like you don't trust it.

Comment: I am trying to test Sentry is being utilized and the message is formatted as expected

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not completely sure of what do you want to test exactly, but this works for me:

```
class Test
  def self.test
    begin
      1 / 0
    rescue => exception
      Raven.capture_exception(exception)
    end
  end
end
```

In a test, I can setup an RSpec spy: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/spies

```
it 'calls raven capture_exception' do
  allow(Raven).to receive(:capture_exception) # Setup the spy

  Test.test # Call the function that uses Raven.capture_exception

  expect(Raven).to have_received(:capture_exception) # Check that the spy was called
end
```